# How to use the IN clause in an JPA @Query annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, entitygraph

I have defined this method

```
 @Query("select cs from CenterStudy cs where cs.id in (?1)")
 @EntityGraph(value = "centerStudyAndNotifiedUsers", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
 List<CenterStudy> findAllByIdsWithCenterAndUsers(List<Long> ids);
```

The list with the ids is not null, nor empty, but I always get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the way the IN clause it's defined.

Any suggestions are well welcomed!

Comment: because you are using a positional parameter (?1) rather than named (:param), and something is expecting named?

Comment: I have tried the following approach too, but I get the same NullPointerException: `@Query("select cs from CenterStudy cs where cs.id in (:ids)")
    @EntityGraph(value = "centerStudyAndNotifiedUsers", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    List<CenterStudy> findAllByIdsWithCenterAndUsers(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common issue, a bug in `Hibernate` which you can find at :

**[NullPointer when combining JPQL query with in clause and @NamedEntityGraph](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9230)** where it says that:

> When you combine a JPQL query with an in clause and a @NamedEntityGraph
>   you get a NullPointerException in org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67) when you execute the query.

So you would have to remove the `@EntityGraph` annotation here in order to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<DealInfo> getDealInfos(List<String> dealIds) {
        String queryStr = "SELECT NEW com.admin.entity.DealInfo(deal.url, deal.url, deal.url, deal.url, deal.price, deal.value) " + "FROM Deal AS deal where deal.id in :inclList";
        TypedQuery<DealInfo> query = em.createQuery(queryStr, DealInfo.class);
        query.setParameter("inclList", dealIds);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Works with JPA 2

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this issue before. I fixed it using named parameteres instead of positional parameters.
Example:

```
"Select p from product where p.id in(?)" -- not working
```

replaced by:

```
"Select p from product where p.id in(:idList)" -- OK
```